# Remove an element from multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm sure this is just an issue on syntax as everything else works.

First I create a nested multidimensional that is held as a session variable across several pages.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit_1"])){
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $size = $_POST['size'];
    $p = $_POST['price'];
    $price = $p * $quantity;
    $item_array = array(0 => array('i_quantity' => $quantity, 'i_name' => $name,'i_size' => $size, 'i_price' => $price));
    $_SESSION["item"][] = $item_array;
}
```

Then i call that code for all my items, create a form button and i create an array ID variable just to give the arrays a number start at -1 so the array begins at 0;

```
<?php
$arrayID = -1;
if(empty($_SESSION["item"])){?>
<?php }
else{       
  // add a foreach loop to display all the session items, if exsited. 
  foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $key){   
  foreach($key as $list){
     $arrayID += 1;
     //displays all the items here
     <form method="POST">
       <input type="submit" name="remove">              
     </form>
  }}}
  ?>
```

All the items appear on the page as they should, now What I would like is use that form button to unset the specific looped array item with corresponding remove button.

The below is my best guess.

```
  if(isset($_POST["remove"])){
     unset($_SESSION["item"][$arrayID]);
  }
```

I have put it inside and out of the for loop, with no luck so far. Tried several other options with changing $arrayID to $key and $list based on other stack overflow suggestions, but no luck. I think my issue is that its a nested array and just don't know the syntax to call the specific item and how to link that to the button function.

Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a hidden field with the index to determine which session index it is. After that you can use the variable to unset the session.

Change your foreach look to something like this:

```
<?php
$arrayID = -1;
if(empty($_SESSION["item"])){?>
<?php }
else{       
  // add a foreach loop to display all the session items, if exsited. 
  foreach($_SESSION['item'] as $key){   
  foreach($key as $list){
     $arrayID += 1;
     //displays all the items here
?> <!-- Close PHP tag !-->
     <form method="POST">
       <input type="submit" name="remove">     
       <input type="hidden" name="removeIndex" value="<?=$arrayId?>">                         
     </form>
<!-- Re-open PHP tag !--><?php  
  }}}
  ?>
```

And your PHP code which catch the remove event to something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST["remove"])){
 unset($_SESSION["item"][$_POST["removeIndex"]]);
}
```

Also note the close and open PHP tags i added. You can't display something in PHP without echo or closing the PHP tag.

Comment: Thank you, and sorry about not included the php specifics before. I did have them all in.